Why Magic Eden and Solscan displays different data for one token?
Recently I have minted a NFT collection and I am going to list it to Magic Eden. But I got problem on that. When I see my NFT on Solscan and MagicEden they are showing different data for that. Why this is happening? I want to get help as soon as possible.
There are the links for NFT.
https://solscan.io/token/G7iMRUitpN5ybPSbrNnhv8fDBkNsGT6tqfxSJxUxUiNY#transactions
https://magiceden.us/item-details/G7iMRUitpN5ybPSbrNnhv8fDBkNsGT6tqfxSJxUxUiNY
